# Django equivalent of SqlAlchemy's literal_column

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, sqlalchemy

Trying to port some SqlAlchemy to Django and I've got this tricky little bit:

```
version = Column(
     BIGINT,
     default=literal_column(
         'UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)'
     ),
     nullable=False)
```

What's the best option for porting the `literal_column` bit to Django? Best idea I've got so far is a function to set as the default that executes the same raw sql, but I'm not sure if there's an easier way? My google-foo is failing me there.

Edit: the reason we need to use a timestamp created by mysql is that we are measuring how out of date something is (so we need to actually know *time*) and we want, for correctness, to have only one time-stamping authority (so that we don't introduce error using python functions that look at system times, which could be different across servers).

At present I've got:

```
def get_current_timestamp(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row

version = models.BigIntegerField(default=get_current_timestamp)
```

which, at this point, sounds like my best/only option.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html#python-executed-functions

Comment: Does it *need* to use this notation?

Comment: @Thomas yes, it does. I'll edit the question to include why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about having a central time authority:

```
import time

version = models.BigIntegerField(
    default = lambda: int(time.time()*1000000) )
```

To bend the database to your will:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import ExpressionNode

class NowInt(ExpressionNode):
    """ Pass this in the same manner you would pass Count or F objects """

    def __init__(self):
        super(Now, self).__init__(None, None, False)

    def evaluate(self, evaluator, qn, connection):
        return '(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000000 + MICROSECOND(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))', []

### Model

version = models.BigIntegerField(default=NowInt())
```

because expression nodes are not callables, the expression will be evaluated database side.

Comment: We're using timestamps because we actually need to know *time*-- that column is going to be used to tell us by how much time something is out of date. Further, I need to use the database to give me a timestamp for consistency, so I can't actually use a function like time.time(), or any python function for time. Sounds like I need to just go with my original idea of calling a function as the default that executes the SA sql...

Comment: Your proposed solution still makes a round-trip through the application, meaning a variable time offset. I've updated the question to use a subclass of ExpressionNode, allowing you to place raw SQL into the database.

Comment: Gonna give you answer credit because that looks reasonable, though I already wrote code to just execute the whole thing as raw sql.